# Ошибка переполнения

Tags: reactjs, typescript, rest, рекурсия

При вызове метода fetchData через clearInterval появляется ошибка и все исчезает, смотрел вроде бы проблема в каких-то рекурсивных вызовах, как от этого избавиться непонятно
Ошибка: Uncaught Error: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops.

```
export class CryptoCurrency extends React.Component<CryptoCurrencyProps, CryptoCurrencyState>{
constructor(props: CryptoCurrencyProps) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {usd: null, error: '', status: CryptoEnum.NONE, intervalId: null};
    this.remove = this.remove.bind(this);
}

componentDidMount() {
    this.fetchData();
    let intervalObj = setInterval(() => this.fetchData(), 5000);
    this.setState({intervalId: intervalObj})
}

fetchData() {
    fetch(`https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/price?fsym=${this.props.cryptoName}&tsyms=USD&api_key=${API_KEY}`)
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(
            (result) => {
                this.setState({
                    usd: result.USD
                });
            },
            (error) => {
                this.setState({
                    error: error
                });
            }
        )
}

remove() {
    this.props.removeCurrency(this.props.cryptoName);
}

componentDidUpdate(prevProps: CryptoCurrencyProps, prevState: CryptoCurrencyState) {
    if (prevState.usd && this.state.usd != null) {
        if (prevState.usd > this.state.usd) {
            this.setState({ status: CryptoEnum.DOWN });
        } else if (prevState.usd < this.state.usd) {
            this.setState({ status: CryptoEnum.UP });
        } else {
            this.setState({ status: CryptoEnum.EQUAL });
        }
    }
}

componentWillUnmount(){
    if (this.state.intervalId){
        clearInterval(this.state.intervalId);
    }
}

render(): any {
    return <div>
        {this.props.cryptoName}{this.state.usd} {this.state.status} <button onClick={this.remove}>Удалить</button>
    </div>
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

постоянно обновляется компонент видимо в этом была ошибка, удалил строчку`else { this.setState({ status: CryptoEnum.EQUAL }); }` в `componentDidUpdate`